# Spark Streaming Connection Refused

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, ngrok, socat

I am trying to run the Spark Streaming [sample program](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.4.0/examples/src/main/python/streaming/network_wordcount.py) slightly modified as follows :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingNetworkWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)                                  # 2nd parameter is duration in seconds

    lines = ssc.socketTextStream('localhost', 5101)
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
                  .map(lambda word: (word, 1))\
                  .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
    
    counts.pprint()
    #counts.toDF().write.csv("outputDir",mode="append")
    #counts.saveAsTextFiles('output','pm')
    
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I am running this in Google Colab using the following technique.First I create ngrok tunnel so that I can expose port 1234 to the internet.

```
public_url = ngrok.connect(1234,"tcp")
```

Then I use socat to create a forwarding mechanism from port 1234 to port 5101. I run the socat command in an xterm simulation created by colab-xterm

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:1234 TCP4:localhost:5101
```

Then I execute the spark-streaming job by submitting it in a second xterm as follows

```
spark-submit wcstream.py
```

Program runs by keeps saying it is not getting any data, which is fine because I have not pumped any data as yet.

Last step I push data from to the ngrok public address

```
<NgrokTunnel: "tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:17078" -> "localhost:1234">
```

by running the following command from a Colab cell

```
!echo 'Hello throuugh TCP tunnel 4' > /dev/tcp/0.tcp.ngrok.io/17078
```

at this point socat throws and error

```
/content# socat TCP4-LISTEN:1234 TCP4:localhost:5101
2023/05/30 05:25:49 socat[8041] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:5101, 16): Connection refused
```

My question is, obviously, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this. I am aware that the netcat approach can be used and have used the same successfully with this same program. However, I am doing all this to see if I can send data to a Spark Streaming program in Colab FROM AN EXTERNAL source. Hence all this effort. Will be grateful for any guidance.

Here is the [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11RzVuPw01cOGj9Z4B_VV681ZyXKCSkQN?usp=sharing), in case anyone wants to try this out.

Comment: If I use nc -lk 5101, the spark streaming can accept data from 5101, but if I use socat, then spark streaming cannot recognise, receive data from 5101 ... this is where the problem lies. I do not know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I solved the problem with a 'relay' program -- a python program that transports messages from one port to another -- but since the program was written by using chatGPT, i am not allowed to post this solution here.